# How to remove reference of a jar file in a java based web application?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, jar, tomcat6

I have a java based web application, which has certain java files and due to some need, i have added some jar files with in the project and made it project specific.

Now, While deploying them in production, I see, that the web file server (tomcat6) already has those jar files in its global library. Now, How do i remove reference of that jar file it, with out disturbing my code(which is working fine).

I saw in other article saying we just have to change the build path to refer the global library instead of local library.

Finally I have 2 questions.

1. How to do this?
2. If i'm working on windows and using path while configuring the build path, will it not be a problem if i deploy it in Unix environment.?

Please suggest. Also, its the problem with servlet-api.jar.

I use eclipse IDE. So how to perform these changes in eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

Open your web project in eclipse and right click on the project. click on Properties and then choose build path and remove the jars you want to remove under the tab 'Libraries' and then export the war and deploy it in your tomcat6 server. if you want to run your web application in eclipse, you have to configure the server libraries by clicking 'Add Library' button in build path and then choose server runtime and choose the tomcat6 server configured in eclipse. Hope this helps